# Rust: Safely terminate running threads inside a ThreadPool?

Tags: rust, borrow-checker, ownership

I followed the official Rust documentation that shows you how to write a multi-threaded HTTP server. They walk you through constructing a thread pool that's backed by individual workers, where each worker has its own thread. The thread pool will execute `Job` instances and pass them along to workers through the MPSC implementation.

This is what the code looks like, per the docs, and the full guide is [here](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch20-02-multithreaded.html#creating-a-similar-interface-for-a-finite-number-of-threads).

```
struct Worker {
    id: usize,
    thread: thread::JoinHandle<()>
}

impl Worker {
    fn new(id: usize, receiver: Arc<Mutex<mpsc::Receiver<Job>>>) -> Worker {
        let thread = thread::spawn(move || loop {
            let job = receiver.lock().unwrap().recv().unwrap();
            println!("Receiver {} received a job.", id);
            job();
        });
        Worker { id, thread }
    }

    fn get_thread(&self) -> &thread::JoinHandle<()> {
        return &self.thread;
    }
}
```

I want to add an additional function: `shutdown()` to my Worker implementation, i.e.

```
    fn shutdown(&mut self) {
        &self.thread.join();
    }
```

I would call this from the main thread, thereby waiting on all the threads to complete before the program ends execution. However, the shutdown function above gives me this error:

```
error: src/main.rs:31: cannot move out of `self.thread` which is behind a mutable reference
error: src/main.rs:31: move occurs because `self.thread` has type `JoinHandle<()>`, which does not implement the `Copy` trait
```

I declared self as `&mut self` since I'll be mutation self.thread. What am I overlooking?

I *think* it's telling me that by calling `&self.thread.join()`, I'm going to destroy the `thread::JoinHandle<()>` that belongs to this worker instance, and I'm not allowed to do that? Then how would I kill this thread?

Secondly, I recognize that my thread has an infinite loop, and so technically calling join on this thread will just cause the main thread to hang. How should I go about breaking out of the thread? Pass a shared reference to my Worker and have the worker check its value, breaking out from the loop?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So first of all, I am guessing you have a `ThreadPool` struct. You would need to implement the `Drop` trait for that struct such that the joining of all threads is done when the entire `ThreadPool` is being dropped, you can't really do so on a per worker basis.

```
impl Drop for ThreadPool {
    fn drop(&mut self) {
        for worker in &mut self.workers {
            println!("Shutting down worker {}", worker.id);

            if let Some(thread) = worker.thread.take() {
                thread.join().unwrap();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The `take()` call is important here because we want to take out the `Some` variant of the option. If the thread is already `None`, we don't need to call join.

Shutting down a thread pool in any language requires some central signal to be acknowledged by all threads, not just one. If this was C++, you might check an atomic bool in the top of your thread's work function, and if it's true, return. While you could do that in rust, I will assume you want to follow a method closer to the project presented in the book itself, which is messages.

Instead of a job, you want to use a message type in your channel, such that you have two variants, a job message and a terminate message.

```
type Job = Box<dyn FnOnce() + Send + 'static>;
enum Message {
    NewJob(Job),
    Terminate,
}
```

And your `ThreadPool` would be

```
pub struct ThreadPool {
    workers: Vec<Worker>,
    sender: mpsc::Sender<Message>,
}
```

Then, your worker function would look more like this, similar to [this section of the book](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch20-03-graceful-shutdown-and-cleanup.html)

```
impl Worker {
    fn new(id: usize, receiver: Arc<Mutex<mpsc::Receiver<Message>>>) -> Worker {
        let thread = thread::spawn(move || loop {
            let message = receiver.lock().unwrap().recv().unwrap();

            match message {
                Message::NewJob(job) => {
                    println!("Worker {} got a job; executing.", id);

                    job();
                }
                Message::Terminate => {
                    println!("Worker {} was told to terminate.", id);

                    break;
                }
            }
        });
```

Now, you also mentioned your program hanging , with no way to externally shut it down. It's probably easier to use a signal handling crate than try to implement this yourself at first. One option is the `singal_hook` crate:

```
use signal_hook::{iterator::Signals, SIGINT};
use std::{error::Error, thread, time::Duration};

fn main() -> Result<(), Box<dyn Error>> {
    let signals = Signals::new(&[SIGINT])?;

    thread::spawn(move || {
        for sig in signals.forever() {
            drop(pool);
        }
    });

    Ok(())
}
```

This will terminate the program when you do ctrl+c on your keyboard

Comment: Thank you for the very nice explanation, but the line ` if let Some(thread) = worker.thread.take() {` throws a compiler error for me. I get: method cannot be called on `JoinHandle<()>` due to unsatisfied trait bounds. the following trait bounds were not satisfied:
`JoinHandle<()>: Iterator`
which is required by `&mut JoinHandle<()>: Iterator`

Comment: One follow up question – with the way we're passing a Message::Terminate enum to signal for the thread to break out of the loop, the sender would have to send one terminate call for each thread, right? Since any message that's passed in is only received by one receiver, we'd have to terminate them one by one.

Comment: @Beebunny `thread: thread::JoinHandle<()>` needs to change to `thread: Option<thread::JoinHandle<()>>`

Comment: Thanks @loganfsmyth. I changed it to `Option<thread::JoinHandle<()>>`. Later on, I'm doing something like: `if let Some(thread) = self.thread.take() { thread.join(); }`

Comment: @Beebunny Don't forget the `.unwrap()` on `.join()`.